# Best way to display an app is in Offline Mode?

Tags: online-offline

My app has multiple modes fully online, offline and merging mode. what would be the best way to show the user that he is currently running on offline mode, so some features won't be available?

Comment: Welcome to the community! It's kind of difficult to make suggestions without much context. For instance, what is the app used for, what it is about? How does it look like, and in what context is it important that a user is in on- or offline mode? Are there screens you can show?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell user if they are offline or online?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89700/how-to-tell-user-if-they-are-offline-or-online)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is something that is not too intrusive but still lets them know.

In QuickBooks for example, they let you know when the app is starting in offline mode and that all the features may not be available, then you click to continue. After if you try to access those features a prompt comes up telling the user they are in offline mode and to switch to online mode if they want to use that feature.

If it's a desktop app with a title bar you can also include (offline mode) in brackets.

Hope this helps!